# translated texts not aligned to baseline

Tags: css, sass, css-animations, css-transforms

i used translateY to animate the numbers to spin like a slot machine.

```scss
$line-height: 19px;

.example {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.room {
  height: $line-height;
}

.rolling {
  transition: 300ms transform ease-in-out;
  
  @for $i from 0 through 9 {
    [data-value='#{$i}'] & {
      transform: translateY(($i - 9) * 10%);
    }
    
    .room:nth-child(#{$i}) & {
      transition-delay: $i * 100ms;
    }
  }
}

.digit {
  height: $line-height;
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: $line-height;
}
```

```html
<div class="example ">
  <div class="room" data-value="1">
    <div class="rolling">
      <div class="digit">9</div>
      <div class="digit">8</div>
      <div class="digit">7</div>
      <div class="digit">6</div>
      <div class="digit">5</div>
      <div class="digit">4</div>
      <div class="digit">3</div>
      <div class="digit">2</div>
      <div class="digit">1</div>
      <div class="digit">0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="room" data-value="2">
    <div class="rolling">
      <div class="digit">9</div>
      ...
  -->
</div>
```

when I checked it out on my Mac, it looked fine.

but on my Android phone(Galaxy S10+), I noticed that the numbers were not aligned to the baseline.

| translated numbers | normal |
| --- | --- |
| [image: numbers not aligned to baseline] | [image: numbers aligned to baseline] |

I fixed height and line-height properties to 19px, but they still weren't aligned.

how can I make them align to the baseline?

Here you can see: https://codepen.io/KhajiitSneak/pen/jOQmVQr

Thanks!

Comment: CSS [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) might help you

Comment: Using percentages might result in some odd behaviour. Have you tried using `transform: translateY(($i - 9) * 19px);` instead, to see if that would fix it?

Comment: @SteffenAndreasKloster I tried it, but it didn't fix it...

Comment: @Reyno you mean vertical-align: middle?